# Same mnt but different rigth

Tags: linux, administrator, redhat-enterprise-linux, cifs

I Have 2 server and the same mount ( CIFS windows machine ) but the files and folder print different permissions.

Server1 redhat7

```
//10.XXX.XXX.XX/nas_usil                             500G  460G   41G  92% /mnt/nas_usil

drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root       0 Oct 25 16:41 validated
```

Server2 redhat7

```
   //10.XXX.XXX.XX/nas_usil                             500G  460G   41G  92% /mnt/nas_usil

drwx------. 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner       0 Oct 25 16:41 validated
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would try setting the permissions you want on the mount point (without the network location mounted).  This is a step I often forget when initially setting up a new network mount.

Remember to unmount the drive first.

`sudo chmod 777 /mnt/nas_usil`

Also, I'm noticing the ownership is different between the two systems.  You may want to conform that as well -- using chown useryouwant:groupyouwant /mnt/nas_usil on whichever is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I have not tested this solution because i'am really curious how it's possible to print differents permissions to the same files/folder. I am root on twice servers

Comment: The permissions you are seeing in your output above are for the local folder.  The smb permissions are different.  Samba is confusing in that you will always have two different sets of permissions to keep track of.  Probably why I often forget this step.

Comment: Sorry please can you retry to explain me ? I'am little bit confusing.

Comment: In Linux you have one set of permissions, that's the 777 or drwxrwxrwx that you are seeing above (for the first mounting).  Those are set on the local machine for that mount point.  They are not the permissions set by Samba (which represent the second set of permissions) on the server, and some user may or may not be able to access smb based on different permissions.

Comment: Since you set the Linux permissions locally, it is easy to set two different hosts with different permissions for the same network mount since each of those hosts has its own folder where the mount is to take place (and each host will assign different permissions to that mount point folder).  More clear?

Comment: Hoo ok I think I understood, that why you asked me to umount it and remount with the rigth set of permissions. I layer of permissions is seted when the mount is done and you have another layer of permissions set by samba. But how can you known which real permission is set for the files ?

Comment: Because if you run the chown or chmod while the network drive is mounted it can have effects on the contents there and you only want to change the mount location permissions.  Then remount (either reboot or ```mount -a```) and you should see what you are after.  Let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot, I cannot vote I have not enougth Reputation but I will do when I got my 15 :D

Comment: Since this is your question you should be able to accept this as the accepted answer.

Comment: done, I will test and I'll come back confirm :d